# How to add user to procmod group?

Tags: linux, macos, cocoa, unix

I am trying to run a project that requires user to be in procmod group.

What is it, and how do I add a user to that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command to add user to `procmod` group

```
sudo chgrp procmod executablepath
```

Apple script

```
do shell script "sudo chgrp procmod executablepath" with administrator privileges
```

`procmod` user can use `task_for_pid` function (Tiger os).

From [taskgated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/taskgated.8.html) -- task_for_pid access control daemon

> the old (Tiger) convention that a process with a primary effective
>   group of procmod or
>                 procview is allowed to get task ports